# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: syntax

I was wondering if someone could help me with this error. I am new to writing shell script so here is my problem. When I run the following script it gives the error, 
line 31: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
g.remove rast=tmp
i=1
while [ $i !=366 ]
do
     j=1951
     r.mapcalc "tmptot = 0.0"
     r.mapcalc "tmpsum = 0.0"
     r.mapcalc "tmptot2 = 0.0"

     while [$j !=2008 ]
     do
         g.copy rast=prec$j.$i,tmp
         r.mapcalc "tmp2 = if(isnull(tmp),0.0,tmp) + tmptot"
         r.mapcalc "tmptot = tm2"
         r.mapcalc "tm3 = if(isnull(tmp),0.0,tmp*tmp) + tmptot2"
         r.mapcalc "tmptot2 = tm3"
         r.mapcalc "tmp4 = if(isnull(tmp),0.0,1) + tmpsum"
         r.mapcalc "tmpsum = tmp4"
         g.remove rast=tmp,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4
         j=`expr $j + 1~
     done

    r.mapcalc "tmp5 = tmptot / tmpsum"
    r.mapcalc "tmp6 = (tmptot * tmptot) / tmpsum"
    r.mapcalc "tmpvar = sqrt((tmptot2 - tmp6) / (tmpsum - 1))"
    g.rename rast=tmp5,av$i
    g.rename rast=tmpvar,sd$i
    g.rename rast=tmpsum,sum$i
    g.remove rast=tmp6

   i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be your problem:

```
j=`expr $j + 1~
```

Replace it with:

```
j=`expr $j + 1`
```

Comment: @user25827 you're welcome! glad to hear that helped! please mark it as the answer if you considered as such and up-vote if you find it useful =)